# Splitting a nested dictionary into a list of single-key paths

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

So let's say I have a dictionary:

```
{"a": {"b": 1,
       "c": 2,
       "d": {"e": 3,
             "f": 4,
            }
      }
 "g": {"h": 5,
       "i": 6
      }
}
```

I've been trying to find a way to map this dictionary into a list of "paths" to each end-value, as follows:

```
[
{"a": {"b": 1}},
{"a": {"c": 2}},
{"a": {"d": {"e": 3}}},
{"a": {"d": {"f": 4}}},
{"g": {"h": 5}},
{"g": {"i": 6}}
]
```

Where each list entry is a single-key nested dictionary. I assume this can be done using some form of depth-first walk with recursion, but I'm not very familiar with programming recursive functions, and also don't know if that's even the best approach.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need it to be list of dict? or list of lists is also fine?

Comment: A list of dict would be better.

Comment: in your sample could you have empty dict  {"i" :{}}  for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that a recursion is a good approach. Here is what I would do. Using a generator (i.e. yield-ing values) has the advantage that we don't have to have a variable gathering the individual result items.

The variable `_revpath` contains the "path" of dict keys leading to a value, but in reversed order, because at the end of the recursion we want to create a nested dict from inner to outer dict.

```
test = {"a": {"b": 1,
       "c": 2,
       "d": {"e": 3,
             "f": 4,
            }   
      },  
 "g": {"h": 5,
       "i": 6
      }   
}

def walkdict(d, _revpath=[]):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key, value in d.items():
            yield from walkdict(value, [key] + _revpath)
    else:
        for key in _revpath:
            d = {key: d}
        yield d

print(list(walkdict(test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to build the list of nodes you pass throught

```
def paths(values, parents=None):
    results = []
    parents = parents or []
    for k, v in values.items():
        if isinstance(v, int):
            results.append(keys_to_nested_dict([*parents, k], v))
        else:
            results.extend(paths(v, [*parents, k]))
    return results
```

Then when you reach an leaf, an `int`, transform that list of nodes, into a nested dict

```
def keys_to_nested_dict(keys, value):
    result = {}
    tmp = result
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        tmp[k] = {}
        tmp = tmp[k]
    tmp[keys[-1]] = value
    return result
```

---

```
print(keys_to_nested_dict(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1))  # {'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}

x = {"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2, "d": {"e": 3, "f": 4, }},
     "g": {"h": 5, "i": 6}}

print(paths(x))
# [{'a': {'b': 1}}, {'a': {'c': 2}}, {'a': {'d': {'e': 3}}}, {'a': {'d': {'f': 4}}}, {'g': {'h': 5}}, {'g': {'i': 6}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same output, but a little tweak can you a lot of efforts & complexity

```
 sample = {"a": {"b": 1,"c": 2,"d": {"e": 3,"f": 4}},"g": {"h": 5,"i": 6}}
 from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record    
 flat = nested_to_record(sample, sep='_')
```

Output

```
{'a_b': 1, 'a_c': 2, 'a_d_e': 3, 'a_d_f': 4, 'g_h': 5, 'g_i': 6}
```

Now, whenever you wish to know the possible paths, just iterate over the keys of this dictionary & split('_') will give you the entire path & associated value